# ngTable: Cannot read property "page"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am trying to implement ngTable to display json from rest call. In my factory js, I defined the method for the http get request to obtain all records in this case.

```
ristoreApp.factory("fmFactory", ['$http', '$window',
    function ($http, $window) {
        var service = {};

        service.getAll = function () {
            var url = SERVER + "/ristore/foundation/";
            return $http({
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.getItem("access_token")},
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                crossOrigin: true
            })
        }

        return service;
    }]);
```

ngTable is set up in my controller js

```
ristoreApp.controller("fmCtrl",
    ['$scope', 'fmFactory', 'NgTableParams', function($scope, fmFactory, NgTableParams) {
        $scope.selection = '0';
        $scope.reports = [];
        $scope.fmSearch = function () {
            if ($scope.selection == '0') {
                fmFactory.getAll().success(function (data) {
                    $scope.reports = data;
                    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                        page: 1,            // show first page
                        count: 10          // count per page
                    }, {
                        total: $scope.reports.length, // length of data
                        getData: function ($defer, params) {
                            $defer.resolve($scope.reports.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

Nothing fancy, just simple pagination with 10 records per page. However, I got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined` for the method `params.page()` in `$defer.resolve()`. This is very strange. Apparently 'page' is defined in the parameter section of `NgTableParams`. Why does it complain it is not defined?

EDIT:

Based on the [link](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/JdwwrR/?editors=101) from Sergii's answer I removed the $defer and changed my controller js to the following:

```
ristoreApp.controller("fmCtrl",
    ['$scope', 'fmFactory', 'NgTableParams', function($scope, fmFactory, NgTableParams) {
        $scope.selection = '0';
        $scope.reports = [];
        $scope.fmSearch = function () {
            if ($scope.selection == '0') {
                    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                        page: 1,            // show first page
                        count: 10          // count per page
                    }, {
                        getData: function (params) {
                            return fmFactory.getAll().then(function(data) {
                                params.total(data.inlineCount);
                                return data;
                            });
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

And yet nothing displayed but a bunch of lines. The http call url has been tested and returns correct promise using rest api tester.

Comment: this way is deprecated `getData: function ($defer, params)` - it is there only for backword compatibility, directly return data/promise...

Comment: can you remove $defer and just receive params and see if that fixes the problem... another issue is make sure you are injecting `NgTableParams` correctly and check if its not undefined

Comment: I've got similar issue. also i want add one important detail. My error is same but in debug mode i see **params is undefined** and from undefined params page can not be taken. 
@ddd if you find solution faster than me, please add here answer.

Comment: Is question closed? Have you problems yet? Is it same or different problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in comment **params is undefined**, but exception was wrapped\processed by angular that is reason of partly correct exception information.

I believe this problem appears because of you are using newest *[ng-table-1.0.0](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table)* library for now. If you navigate to [Angular ngTableDynamic example:server-side list](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/JdwwrR/?editors=101) or [Angular ngTable example:server-side list](http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/VLqqjP?editors=101) please pay attantion that API to load data was changed.

```
  getData: function(params) {
    // ajax request to api
    return yourFactory.get(params.url()).$promise.then(function(data) {
      params.total(data.inlineCount);
      return data.results;
    });
  }
```

In your parameter *$defer* also different object (object is **params**). If you'll try apply provided solution, please make sure that you changed correctly parameters:

```
params.url() - should be pagination filter like {page: 0, size: 10}
data.inlineCount - total elements on server side
data.results - data list from server side
```

I hope my investigation helped not only me to fix this problem.

Comment: So instead of having `getData` inside `fmFactory.getAll().success(function (data)`, I should place `fmFactory.getAll` in getData? I am not using $resource and I have $http is wrapped up in the `getAll()` method of my factory (see factory source code in my post). Therefore factory does not have `get()`.

Comment: In the example `Api.get(params.url())`, what is this url? Where is it defined?

Comment: _params.url()_ returns _{page: 1, size: 10}_ You can check it in debug mode.

Comment: In your code part was used **getData: function ($defer, params)**. But should be **getData: function (params)** (for ngTable version from 1.0.0)

Comment: Do you have some exceptions yet? Your edited part now is better, but it also can have other issues. To solve which you need check your model state in debug mode. It you need more advises, share more details please about current state.